# Login on colab with gcloud without service account

Tags: python, gcloud, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to authenticate on a colab file to be able to make bigquery requests, access drive, etc. I've been using :

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Which works great but asks for credentials every time the session times out (every 12h I think) and which requires human interaction (clicking on the link, copy the token, paste it).

I know I can use [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/) cli to authenticate using a 'service account'. But I don't have access to it in the organization I'm working in. However, I can get an [`access-token`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-access-token) and an [`identity-token`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token) from gcloud.

Is there a way to authenticate using these tokens, simply by running a cell, and without further interactions ? What is the purpose of these tokens anyway ?

*P.S: I'm okay with hacky solutions.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I did :

**Step 1 : Sign In manually once**

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

**Step 2 : Dump keys**

```
!cat adc.json
```

Then copy the values of the following keys : `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token`

**Step 3 : Run that code whenever you want to authenticate**

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

import httplib2
import json

from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client import GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, client
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

auth_key = {
  "client_id": "...",
  "client_secret": "...",
  "refresh_token": "..."
}

credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
    access_token=None,
    client_id=auth_key['client_id'],
    client_secret=auth_key['client_secret'],
    refresh_token=auth_key['refresh_token'],
    token_expiry=None,
    token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
    user_agent=None,
    revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI)

credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
cred = json.loads(credentials.to_json())
cred['type'] = 'authorized_user'

with open('adc.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(cred, outfile)

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = credentials
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Now you don't have to do any interaction with the browser, just run the cell.

Comment: This token expires in 24 hours, I think. I use a service-account key, embedded in the notebook instead.

Comment: I updated the answer. It's now refreshing the token.

Comment: Do you have any article that explain your code? I want to know what and why each line works.

Comment: Not really, but I mean `oauth2client` is a Google library so I would expect it to work normally.

Comment: You can find some doc here [github.com/googleapis/oauth2client](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client)

Comment: I am using Colab, and if this works, I won't have to authenticate each time I start a notebook.  That would be amazing.

Comment: I followed these steps, and afterwards tried to call !gsutil, and it says "ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."

Comment: I am trying to authenticate this way to clone a private repo but am still being told by Gcloud that I am not authenticated. Any other options?

Comment: `!cat adc.json` doesn't work. There's no such file. Did something change? I don't think the `google.colab` library creates such a file anymore, if it ever did.